# node.js require() in javascript tag equalivant

Tags: javascript, node.js

Running a node.js app provides a means to load an included js script as a class/variable.

--- app.js ---

```js
var mine = require('myClass');
mine.DoSomething();
```

How does node know that MyClass is the file "js/MyClassFile.js"?
What is the HTML `<script>` equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It use something called [modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).
For example in `js/MyClassFile.js` there must be something like

`exports.myClass = function (r) {
  return {DoSomething: function(){} };
};`

> What is the HTML equivalent?

If by html, you mean browser, then there is options like [browserify](http://browserify.org/), [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/), etc, etc

for more info check [Writing Modular JavaScript With AMD, CommonJS & ES Harmony](https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) by Addy Osmani out.

Comment: That is pretty much what I was expecting to hear.  The makers of this js script I'm trying to use didn't build it for straight html.  It looks like they started a build of it but then abandoned what I want, didn't mention so in the documentation, and then implemented it in node where the whole concept works as an app.

Answer (score 0):

When you require a file in say app.js, you should use its relative path and export it using module.exports. That's how Node.js knows where to look for it. 

--- app.js ---

```
var mine = require('../myClass')
mine.doSomething();
```

--- myClass.js ---

```
var myClass = {
}
module.exports = myClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

`How does node know that MyClass is the file "js/MyClassFile.js"?`

Node decides it on basis of relative path so if you are in `js` folder and try to use `var mine = require('myClass');` then it means then `myClass` is in `js` folder

for html equivalent you need to use modules but you can do it in `es6` like this, please note es6 support is still limited

```
//  lib/math.js 
export function sum (x, y) { return x + y } 
export var pi = 3.141593

//  someApp.js 
import * as math from "lib/math" 
console.log("2π = " + math.sum(math.pi, math.pi))

//  otherApp.js 
import { sum, pi } from "lib/math" 
console.log("2π = " + sum(pi, pi))
```

otherwise you can look at this [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)